# Firebase Notifications in my flutter App works on iOS in development but doesn't work in production

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on a flutter app using firebase notifications that I receive from a larval Backend it's working on development but when I run the app in Release mode or upload it to TestFlight it doesn't work.

I have created the certificates for production and development and uploaded them to firebase messaging in setting section.

This is the AppDelegate.swift :

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
 if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    }
    if(!UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Notification")) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Notification")
    }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

  // This method will be called when app received push notifications in foreground
     override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
          {
              completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
          }

  }
```